# Python Scipy.stats operations do not work when copied to another machine (where there is no python installed) with the source folder

Tags: python-2.7, import, scipy, portability

I am using Scipy.stats to perform distribution fits on my data. It works perfectly on my machine. But when I package my script with Python source folder, python27.dll and try to run it on another machine (where python is not installed and I do not want to also) by invoking my script like below

**Path/to/Python.exe Path/to/script.py**

I get the follwing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test2.py", line 2, in <module>
   import scipy.stats
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py
", line 344, in <module>
   from .stats import *
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py",
line 173, in <module>
   import scipy.special as special
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.
py", line 636, in <module>
   from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

My script is

```
import sys
import scipy.stats
import numpy
dataarray= [2.45, 3.67, 1.90, 2.56, 1.78, 2.67]
desc =  scipy.stats.describe(dataarray)
print desc
```

This occurs only on Scipy import and scipy operations, all other imports and operations work fine. My purpose is to run this script in different machines without having to actually install python